# SQL Server Mirroring - Should Witness server be dedicated to mirroring?

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

Scenario - SQL Server 2008 R2 Mirrored environment - High Safety synchronous with automated failover.
Witness Server is a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Question: Can the Witness server be used for other SQL purposes? In particular I am wondering if it is possible to complete test restores of database backups on the Witness and then run integrity checks (DBCC CHECKDB) on the restored database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the witness server can do other tasks.

What you've suggested is quite useful.